# NullPointer Exception while passing Bundle from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to android, trying to send a bundle from a Activity to Fragment using

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("name", "XXXXXXX");

FragmentTab1 fTab1 = new FragmentTab1();
fTab1.setArguments(args);
```

and in FragmentTab1 onCreate method as follows:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the view from fragmenttab1.xml
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
      name = bundle.getString("name");
    }
    TextView nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dinesh);
    nameView.setText(name);
    return view;
  }
```

getting `null pointer exception` at  `Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();`

please help me to trace this exception

Comment: Have a look at this discussion (: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment

Answer (score 1):

sorry if my answer is late for you..

Please create first instance of fragment then bundle..and make sure perform transaction on fragment to order to get argument in fragment.

```
FragmentTab1 fTab1 = new FragmentTab1();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("name", "XXXXXXX");
fTab1.setArguments(args);
```

Hope this will resolve null pointer exceptions, you can get argument on fragment's onStart or OnCreateView method..

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment Task

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Static method in your fragment and just pass the Bundle argument to that method that is the simplest method I have found till now.

below Would be a format of the method in your fragment

```
Bundle arg;
public static void setArguments(Bundle Args)
{


    arg=Args;

}
```

and from where you want to set the Arguments just call in this fashion

```
YourFragment.setArguments(Args);
```

Hope You will find this answer helpful

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened with me while working with android studio. However, it is a fault of android studio that it sometimes doesn't add updated code to apk. So it would be better if you run build->Clean and then run the application.